# Why npm, cdnjs, unpkg not support Babel version 7 while GitHub has version 7 stability?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, unpkg

I see at here https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.3.3 . There are Babel version 7.3.3 . However, I see at here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core and

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-standalone

https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone

I don't see Babel version 7.3.3, only version 7 beta. Why npm, cdnjs, unpkg does not support version 7 stability?

Comment: The owner(s) of those libraries needs to package and post them to those locations.